# Can't install Chrome on Ubuntu 18

Tags: command-line, apt, bash, 18.04, google-chrome

When I tried to install a current version of a software, someone [provided the URL](https://askubuntu.com/a/1074072/869955) for where the binaries are located so that it can be used with the command below.

```
curl -silent -location https://blabla | sudo --preserve-env bash -
```

I've been informed that under Linux, it's unusual to download the binaries and install those, like it's common in Windows. Now, I'd like to install Chrome but the command below didn't give me anything useful.

```
sudo apt install chrome
```

I only get the message saying that *Unable to locate package chrome*. So I figure that I probably need to use the syntax with *curl* and *bash*. However, I don't know where I should obtain the URL that's supposed to be used.

At the Chrome's page, there's only a button to download the binaries but that's the Window way, I understand. I prefer to do it properly, as supposed to.

Where do I get the URL to *curl* for installing the binaries?

Comment: @wjandrea It kind of answered my question. I was curious how to install Chrome using the way that I was recommended to use for other software, i.e. curling and bashing it. It seems as an irregularity in Linux when installing different software. Scary... (to a noob like me)

Comment: There are many many ways to install software on Linux. Chrome does not have an install script (which Bash would run), but an install package (a .deb, which dpkg installs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Google Chrome isn't there in official repository of Ubuntu. To install Chrome, download the file from chrome.google.com and to install it,

**GUI**: Right click on downloaded file and open with software centre and then click on install.

**CLI**: Open terminal in the directory and use `sudo dpkg -i filename` where filename is the name of `.deb` file downloaded.

Comment: For details, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/510063/301745) on the duplicate I linked.

Comment: `wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb` downloads the file from the site. Manually adding the repo is not needed, as you say.

Comment: I think you misread my first comment, cause I'm not talking about that answer.