# What does command | sh means in bash?

Tags: bash

This is the command to install Rust:

```
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh
```

what does the `|` do?

I think that curl downloads a .sh file from this link, and sh somehow executes it. How does it work? It isn't working in my Dockerfile, I need to pass `-y` to this `.sh` but I don't know how.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the syntax of pipe and ending dash mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1074067/what-does-the-syntax-of-pipe-and-ending-dash-mean)

Comment: @user68186 yes but how do I pass -y to this script?

Comment: Please edit the question title to represent what you actually need. I don't see `-y` option for `sh` [in the manual](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/sh.1posix.html), where exactly do you want it passed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically enter input in command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/338857/automatically-enter-input-in-command-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you getting these instructions from? It's likely there is documentation that explains how they intend for you to do what you want.

Needless to say, you can pass `-y` [like so](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/491092/19157):

```
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh -s -- -y
```

`-s` instructs `sh` to read from stdin even though there are command line arguments (`-- -y`). The `--` is necessary so `sh` knows to treat `-y` as an argument to the script, and not a flag for `sh` itself.

---

To your actual question, `curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs` downloads some data from https://sh.rustup.rs and outputs it. If you visit that URL, you'll see the contents are a shell script. So that's what you're downloading.

`sh` is a basic shell program that can parse and run this script, such as [Dash](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh) or the [Bourne shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell).

The `|` character pipes the output from the command on the left to the input of the command on the right. So `curl ... | sh` means "Download this text and run it". Although this is a somewhat common pattern for complex installers, it's technically a form of [remote code execution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary_code_execution), and can be risky. Be sure you trust the source before routing arbitrary content from the internet into `sh`, `bash`, `python`, or other shells or programs that process commands on your local machine.

---

As you may have noticed, you could also just download the source code from https://sh.rustup.rs and run it directly:

```
cd ~/Downloads # or wherever you save it to
sh rustup-init.sh -y
```

Comment: sh is just a link pointing to currently configured system shell usually `dash`, think the short name for sh is POSIX shell.

Comment: Right you are, it's `dash` on Ubuntu. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The `|` is a pipe. In your case, you need to uninstall your previously installed rust and install it again.